# Json string to Java object with dynamic keys

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-webflux

I want to insert a REST API response to java object. My sample response as below.

```
    {
        "key1": [
          {
            "name": "test1",
            "id": "id1",            
          }
        ],
        "key2": [
          {
            "name": "test2",
            "id": "id2",            
          },
          {
            "name": "test3",
            "id": "id3", 
          }
        ]
      }
```

For that I created "User" class for repeating object

```
@Data
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String id;    
}
```

API response body only accept `Class<T>` and for that I parsed `Map.class` to that function as I want to insert json response data to `Map<String, List<User>>` instead of java class object.

```
public Mono<Map> getUserInfo(String number) {
        return apiAdaptor.getRequest(urlConfiguration.getUserApi(), Map.class, true
                , number);
    }


public <T> Mono<T> getRequest(String url, Class<T> responseClass, boolean isDds,
                                  String... urlArgs) {
        return Mono.just(this.accessToken)
                .flatMap(token -> this.webClient.get()
                        .uri(url, urlArgs)                     
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .exchange()
                        .flatMap(clientResponse -> getClassResponse(clientResponse, responseClass, isDds))                        
                );
    }


private UserResponse handleSuccess(Map map) {        
        Map<String, List<User>> apiRes = map;
}
```

But when I looping through API response (`apiRes`) it gave "java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to User". As I checked, if Jackson cannot identified the exact format it will automatically converted to "LinkedHashMap". Please help.

Please note that I'm new to java development.

Comment: Can you add, what means _API response body only accepts Class<T>_ ? If you define object as a `Map` it is a `Map` (so `LinkedHashMap`) and there will not be any additional type information. Each _complex_ value will be `Map` also and it is not possible to cast that to `User`.

Comment: please post your code you are using that gives your your error

Comment: @pirho updated the question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to declare class of its own to preserve generic types to be compiled and casted correctly. So like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DynKeyUserMap extends HashMap<String, List<User>> {}
```

Then instead of using `Map.class` use `DynKeyUserMap.class` to prevent casting problems.

Comment: need to hardcoded above created class for unit testing. can you please explain, how to create instance for above. i tried below one but it showing compile error. DynKeyUserMap dynKeyUserMap = new HashMap<String, List<User>>();

Comment: @udith It is just `DynKeyUserMap dynKeyUserMap = new DynKeyUserMap();`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Httpclient you are using for your development. However with a RestTemplate Client you do as below

```
Map<String, List<User>> responseMap= new HashMap<>();
ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<User>>> response =new RestTemplateBuilder().build().getForEntity(url, responseMap.getClass());
```

I used the builder so that default message converters are used.